# Storing complex data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to store some data with various structures in my database.  The way I am trying to do it is to create a record entity and attach entries (attributes) to that record for its conditions/values.

```
Record 1
-> Entity 1 = title:Fruit, dataString:Apple
-> Entity 2 = title:quantity, dataNumber:5
-> Entity 3 = title:color, dataString:red
etc...

Record 2
-> Entity 1 = title:Fruit, dataString:Apple
-> Entity 2 = title:quantity, dataNumber:5
-> Entity 3 = title:color, dataString:green
etc...
```

I want to be able to return all color results where Fruit==Apple quantity==5.  therefore [red,green]

I cant create a table with for each type of record because my data is very complex and has different attributes (entries) associated with each record

```
<?php

    namespace App\ReferenceBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Entry
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\EntryRepository")
     */
    class Entry
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $title;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="data_string", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $dataString;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="data_number", type="float", nullable=true)
         */
        private $dataNumber;


        /**
         * @var App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record[]
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record", mappedBy="entries")
         */
        private $records;

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set title
         *
         * @param string $title
         * @return Record
         */
        public function setTitle($title)
        {
            $this->title = $title;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get title
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getTitle()
        {
            return $this->title;
        }

        /**
         * Set dataString
         *
         * @param string $dataString
         * @return Record
         */
        public function setDataString($dataString)
        {
            $this->dataString = $dataString;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get dataString
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getDataString()
        {
            return $this->dataString;
        }

        /**
         * Set dataNumber
         *
         * @param float $dataNumber
         * @return Record
         */
        public function setDataNumber($dataNumber)
        {
            $this->dataNumber = $dataNumber;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get dataNumber
         *
         * @return float 
         */
        public function getDataNumber()
        {
            return $this->dataNumber;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->records = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Add records
         *
         * @param \App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record $records
         * @return Entry
         */
        public function addRecord(\App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record $records)
        {
            $this->records[] = $records;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove records
         *
         * @param \App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record $records
         */
        public function removeRecord(\App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Record $records)
        {
            $this->records->removeElement($records);
        }

        /**
         * Get records
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getRecords()
        {
            return $this->records;
        }
    }


<?php

namespace App\ReferenceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Record
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\RecordRepository")
 */
class Record
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @var App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry", inversedBy="records")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="link_records_entries",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="record_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="entry_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $entries;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entries = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add entries
     *
     * @param \App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry $entries
     * @return Record
     */
    public function addEntry(\App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry $entries)
    {
        $this->entries[] = $entries;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove entries
     *
     * @param \App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry $entries
     */
    public function removeEntry(\App\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Entry $entries)
    {
        $this->entries->removeElement($entries);
    }

    /**
     * Get entries
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEntries()
    {
        return $this->entries;
    }
}


public function options($matches, $output)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('entry'); 
    $qb->innerJoin('entry.records', 'record'); 
    $qb->innerJoin('record.entries', 'entries'); 



    $qb->where('entry.title = :output');
    $params = ["output" => $output];

    foreach ($matches as $title => $value) { 

        $title1 = str_replace(" ", "_", $title);

        $qb->andWhere('entries.title = :'.$title1.' AND (entries.dataString = :'.$title.'dataString OR entries.dataNumber = :'.$title.'dataNumber)'); 
        $params[$title1] = $title;
        $params[$title."dataString"] = $value;
        $params[$title."dataNumber"] = $value;
    } 

    $qb->setParameters($params);

    $array = $qb 
        ->select('entry.dataString, entry.dataNumber')  
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();


var_dump($array);exit();
```

In the above code $output would be color and $matches would contain quantity and fruit.

Obviously the above code doesnt work because it it trying to find one entry that contains a type and a fruit which is not possible.  I need to return entries that have sibling entries that match my matches array.

I am probably not going about this the right way.  Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok The below seems to do the trick

```
public function options($matches, $output)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('record'); 



    $qb->innerJoin('record.entries', 'entry'); 

    $qb->where('entry.title = :output');
    $params = ["output" => $output];



    foreach ($matches as $title => $value) { 

        $title1 = str_replace(" ", "_", $title)."match";

        $qb->innerJoin('record.entries', $title1.'entries'); 

        $qb->andWhere($title1.'entries.title = :'.$title1   .' AND ('.$title1.'entries.dataString = :'.$title1.'dataString OR '.$title1.'entries.dataNumber = :'.$title1.'dataNumber)'); 

        $params[$title1] = $title;
        $params[$title1."dataString"] = $value;
        $params[$title1."dataNumber"] = $value;
    }


    $qb->setParameters($params);

    $array = $qb  
        //->select('entry1.title, entry1.dataString, entry1.dataNumber, entry.title as title1')
        ->select('entry.dataString, entry.dataNumber')
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();


    $arrayFlat = iterator_to_array(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array)),false);

    $arrayNotNulls = array_filter($arrayFlat, 'strlen');
    $arrayKeysFixed = array_values($arrayNotNulls);

    return $arrayKeysFixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use EAV Structure (Entity, Attribute, Value) - that structure is used in Magento and Drupal. Good luck!:)